# CSS is connected and works with many IDs but cannot edit one single form

Tags: html, css, forms

As said in title, the CSS is connected to the page it is on properly. And the styling works in all aspects except for one single form. Below is some CSS for the form followed by the HTML code for the form.

```css
#form2 input {
  background: black;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#form2 select {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form id="form2" method="post" action="home.php?id=<?php echo $user_id;?>">
  </br>
  <h2>What would you like to ask? Rant away!</h2>
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Write a title" size="92px" />
  <textarea cols="70" rows="6" name="content" ;>Description...</textarea><br/>
  <select name="topic">
      <option> Select Topic</option>
      <?php getTopics() ;?>
     </select>
  <input type="submit" name="sub" value="Post to Timeline" />
</form>
```

Comment: You have no css for your form.

Comment: How so? I posted CSS aiming to edit the input and select parts of the form.
for reference, when testing with a css just for the form, with a border or background or padding etc, nothing happens then either.

Comment: Do you have a style tag around your css?

Comment: The css is saved in a different file and linked

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/home_style.css" media="all"/>

The same CSS sheet also contains CSS for other aspects of the page the HTML snippet is from, such as header and footer where it works flawlessly as well as for another form.

Comment: What is supposed to happen? In the snippet, the controls are styled as expected. You have errors in the HTML - `</br>`, `size="92px"` etc - but I'm sure that won't cause any problems with applying the css. Just with browser crosscompatibility.

Comment: the form won't stylise at all.